# JSON API Callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, callback

Tenho uma dúvida em como filtrar resultados provenientes de uma `API`, e gostaria de saber se alguém já teve este problema anteriormente.

Imaginemos que temos que aceder a uma `API` que está num servidor diferente do nosso e que retorna uma reposta em `JSON` com uma estrutura semelhante à seguinte

```
[
{
"nome": "Joshua",
"sex": "M"
},
{
"name": "Marie",
"sex": "F"
},
{
"name": "Frank",
"sex": "M"
}
]
```

Claro que isto é apenas um exemplo, pois a resposta poderia ser de milhões de resultados. O parametro do `callback` para iniciar a comunicação `JSONP` é `?callback=...?`.

O que eu gostaria de saber é se há uma forma de filtrar estes resultados, imaginemos que queremos apenas retornar pessoas do `sexo` masculino (`M`), sem ter que se fazer uma filtragem do lado do cliente. Lembro que para fazer esta chamada, apenas pode ser feita através de Javascript sem recorrer a outro tipo de linguagem.

A minha primeira ideia seria fazer uma chamada com recurso a jQuery desta forma:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: "https://url-to-api?callback=?",
async: false,
jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
contentType: "application/json",
data:{'sex':'M'},
dataType: 'jsonp',
success: function(json) {
console.dir(json);
},
error: function(e) {
console.log(e.message);
}
```

Alguém sabe uma forma de se fazer uma filtragem ao fazer o request?
Desde já agradeço a disponibilidade.

Comment: Esse é o [pt.so], traduza sua pergunta ou poste no [so].

Comment: Peço desculpa, nem tinha dado conta disso.

Comment: Tranquilo cara.

Comment: Já agora, se souberes como resolver o meu problema... ;)

Comment: Estou tentando entender, comecei há pouco com javascript. Do jeito que você tentou não funcionou?

Comment: Da forma que fiz, apenas retorna a lista toda. Aquilo que queria era filtrar essa lista logo no request., passar parametros. Mas como não tenho controlo na api não sei como passar esses parametros. Não queria fazer loop por todos os objects e ver qual deles é do sexo masculino (M)

Answer (score 1):

Se o site onde vais buscar o JSON não permitir parâmetros de filtragem então tens de fazer isso no lado do cliente.

Dá uma olhada na API desse site.

Fazendo a filtragem no lado do cliente podes usar o `.filter()`. Verifica se o JSON que o site ter passa é processado como JSON ou já como array, vou incluir essa verificação no exemplo em baixo:

```
var parametroFiltragem = 'M';
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "https://url-to-api?callback=?",
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (json) {
        if (typeof json == 'string') json = JSON.parse(json);
        var filtrados = json.filter(function(obj){
            return obj.sex == parametroFiltragem;
        });
        // fazer algo somente com os "filtrados"
    },
    error: function (e) {
        console.log(e.message);
    }
});
```

Comment: A tua solução funciona. E foi aquilo q tinha pensado inicialmente. A questão é que aqui há até 6 paramentros de pesquisa.E a pesquisa pode até ser algo complexa.Por exemplo, é necessário filtrar por preço (maior,menor,entre) e mais outros tipos de combinação. Será uma boa solução em termos de performance?A única informacao que tenho da API é a seguinte:
The tool itself should allow for the user to perform simple filtering based on the criteria listed.The filtering options should be appropriate for its type (numerical etc.).The callback parameter to initiate JSONP communication is “?callback=”

Comment: @Ma1990 por essa descrição em Inglês dizem que dá para fazer filtragem. Podes mostrar o link para a documentação?

Comment: Não tenho qualquer documentação. O único que tenho é o URL da API.

Comment: @Ma1990 e qual é o url?

Comment: @Ma1990, estive a dar uma olhada pelo site da ndivia e não encontro nada que indique parametros para filtrar. Como descobriste essa API? não tens onde perguntar?

Comment: @Ma1990 podes partilhar essa documentação?  a ver se diz lá alguma coisa sobre os filtros...

Comment: O que tem foi aquilo partilhei mais acima. Depois tem o seguinte:

The callback parameter to initiate JSONP communication is “?callback=…”.
Invalid or missing callbacks will invoke a 400 Bad Request
The user should be able to filter against these criterias
• Series number
• Has PhysX
• Has SLI
• Is In Stock
• Is Not A Preorder
• Price Is Below, Above, or Between

Comment: @Ma1990 e recebeste informação que isso dá para fazer no url? ou é para fazeres um filtro no cliente? Fazendo no cliente faz-me sentido, senão vais ter de adivinhar e isso parece-me estranho que te tenham dado uma tarefa para "adivinhares" o que a API faz.

Comment: É para fazer o filtro no cliente O que para mim não faz sentido, é ter que fazer o request de tudo e depois implementar um filtro. Ainda para mais o filtro pode ser bastante complexo, tendo em conta que é para filtrar por imensos parametros.

"We require a javascript-based widget that can be dropped onto a NVIDIA owned property. The widget should pull a JSON feed from a determined location. The JSON feed contains product information, and some purchasing data.
The tool itself should allow for the user to perform simple filtering based on the criteria listed."

Comment: At a minimum, the user should be shown the technologies inside the graphics card, the specifications, the graphics card “image”, and a link to a detail page.
The filtering options should be appropriate for its type (numerical, boolean, etc.)
https://www.nvidia.eu/developer-test/buy.php?callback= 
The callback parameter to initiate JSONP communication is “?callback=…”
Invalid or missing callbacks will invoke a 400 Bad Request
The user should be able to filter against these criterias
• Series number
• Has PhysX
• Has SLI
• Is In Stock
• Is Not A Preorder
• Price Is Below, Above, or Between

Comment: Esta é a documentação do problema, nada mais. O que me leva a crer que é para fazer filtro no lado do cliente depois de fazer o request.

Comment: @Ma1990 exato. Acho que tens de fazer selects no HTML populados com o que o JSON tem baseado nas especificações "Series number • Has PhysX • Has SLI • Is In Stock • Is Not A Preorder • Price Is Below, Above, or Between". Sabes como fazer isso? Se não posso ajudar/adaptar a resposta mais tarde.

Comment: Agradecia a tua ajuda para isso :)

Comment: Olá Sergio. Sempre dá para me auxiliares nesta filtragem? Outra questão. Tendo em conta que se tem que fazer a manipulação depois do success. Como posso fazer fazer o styling do conteúdo? Faço isso na resposta e depois append a um elemento que já exista na página? Há alguma forma de passar o array de objectos para o HTML e fazer lá a manipulação? Como é feito em AngularJS com o ng-repeat.

Comment: @Ma1990 o código para fazer isso não é assim tão simples. Perdi um bom tempinho a montar um exemplo que precisa ser afinado: http://jsfiddle.net/gfrsLx92/ Imagino que é isso que procuras... isso demorou algum tempo e não está a 100%. Saber fazer o resto?

Comment: Obrigado por isto. Estou a pegar a na tua ideia e fazer com AngularJS. Acho que remove a complexidade de "construir" o HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que o código abaixo pode ser o que você está procurando:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "https://url-to-api/pagina",
    data: {
        sex: "M"
    },
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    cache: false,
    success: function (json) {
        alert(json);
    },
    error: function (e) {
        alert(e.statusText +": "+ e.status);
    }
});
```

No seu comentário você falou que a requisição vai ser feita para outro domínio, para isso ativamos o crossDomain, recurso que permite realizar requisição ajax para outros domínios.

Neste caso por default desativei o cache, porém, fica a seu critério utilizar ou não.

No parametro data apenas retirei as aspas da palavra "sex".

> Obs: "o seu filtro por sexo só vai funcionar se a API que está do outro
>   lado tiver implementado este parâmetro como filtro, do contrário você
>   terá que retornar todos os dados e criar o filtro do lado do cliente."